# Enumerate function - only item 1 appearing with numbering

Tags: numbering, lists, enumerate

I am having an issue with my enumerate function - only the 1st item appears to have[i] the other item doesn't have any numbering present.

```
\documentclass{svmono}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[i]
\item One 
\item Two 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Please post a complete, compilable code, reproducing your problem.

Comment: Sorry - I'm brand new to LaTex so just figuring this all out

Comment: `svmono` is not a standard class, so it could be doing anything; the compilable code that Bernard mentioned would include using a standard class that we all have (`article` would be best).  The standard classes don't usually change how enumerate works, so you'd need a package to do that for you.  Looking at the way you've written things, can you try adding `\usepackage{paralist}` after the first line?

Comment: I'm preparing a manuscript for publishing which is why I need to use the svmono class. it seems to work fine when I use the standard numbers for enumerate but when I try to use Roman numerals it no longer seems to work

Comment: What output are you expecting? a list with numbers? in that case, you don't need the `[i]` at all: just  use `\begin{enumerate}`. If you're looking for an output that has i.1 then you should use the label option `\begin{enumerate}[label=i.{\arabic*}]` with the enumitem package

Comment: `enumitem` might be a more flexible choice. If loaded as `\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}` this particular syntax is supported

Comment: Thanks - I've started using enumitem now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need either `enumerate` or `enumitem` to support that syntax.

However, there are some problems.

Let's consider the code

```latex
\documentclass{svmono}
\usepackage{showframe}
%\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First level
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Second level
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Third level
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item Fourth level
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\item Two 
\end{enumerate}

\begin{itemize}
\item First level
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Second level
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Third level
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Fourth level
      \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\item Two 
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

### Output without packages

[image]

### Output after adding `\usepackage{enumerate}`

[image]

### Output after adding `\usepackage{enumitem}`

[image]

### Output after adding `\usepackage{enumitem}` with fixes.

```latex
\documentclass{svmono}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate]{align=left}
\setlist[itemize]{align=left}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First level
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Second level
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Third level
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item Fourth level
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\item Two 
\end{enumerate}

\begin{itemize}
\item First level
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Second level
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Third level
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Fourth level
      \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\item Two 
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Not really the same, but not so distant.

### Code for your application

```latex
\documentclass{svmono}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate]{align=left}
\setlist[itemize]{align=left}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*.]
\item One 
\item Two 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Comments

The `\usepackage{showframe}` line has been added just to properly show the bounding box of the text block. Remove it for your document.

Using `enumerate` would change the appearance of all lists with respect to the `svmono` standard, so it is out of question. With `enumitem` the output is not very different.